# What is with all the DOTA 2 updates?

Tags: dota-2

What is with all the DOTA 2 updates?

I am not sure if anyone else is having this issue but for the past 3 weeks almost every single day when I play DOTA 2 there is an update.

Why is this happening?

Comment: They're updating the game. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Sweet one down vote and a stupid answer. Thanks Guys :)

Comment: I'm not sure what more of an answer you could possibly want...?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Why is the game updating? Because Valve is adding/changing content. Unless you specify what you mean by your question, we can't give you a better answer.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better asking the developers? Downvoting because it is asking for developer intent

Comment: How's that a stupid answer? It's a very good answer which explains exactly why there are so many updates. With a new engine which is a massive change, there's sure to be many new bugs introduced which are remedied as fast as possible with an update. This sort of change is rarely done on a production release so frequent updates are expected.

Comment: @Aequitas, its worth considering that if OP simply does not understand how certain elements would work, this entire concept could be foreign to them. OP is unsure, for one, if anyone else even has to update! I think this is just a case of gamer a bit out of their depth, wanting to make sure that what they are experiencing is normal.

Answer (score 7):

Valve moved DOTA2 to a completely new game engine (Source 2) earlier this month.

Not only did they move to a new engine, but this is the first Source 2 game **ever**.

Not surprisingly, they're finding all sorts of new issues with it.

Comment: Actually it happened [over a year ago](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/187723-valve-quietly-releases-source-2-engine-source-2-version-of-dota-2-and-new-hammer-map-editor), but they only recently admitted to it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Playing on Source2 was only available through the beta client. They only [recently](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Patches) moved the main client over and obsoleted the Source1 client.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That was the map editor and tools.  The game itself only went into beta last month and the regular client only was converted over on September 8th or 9th (reports are conflicting as to when it switched)